# Swift Changing window.rootViewController causes black flash upon willConnectTo in SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, uiscenedelegate

**Problem:**

I am experiencing an issue where there is a black flash when transitioning the window.rootViewController in the SceneDelegate.

Launch Screen -> instant black flash(milaseconds) -> proper window

**Code:**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        var additionalScopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"]

        if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.hasPreviousSignIn() == true){

            print("is true")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { user, error in
            if error != nil || user == nil {
              // Show the app's signed-out state.

               
                guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
                self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                    let vc = AuthenticationViewController()
                self.window?.rootViewController = vc
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                
            } else {
              // Show the app's signed-in state.
                let grantedScopes = user?.grantedScopes
                if (grantedScopes!.contains(additionalScopes[0]) && grantedScopes!.contains(additionalScopes[1])) {
                    print("user has acces to scoped")
                   
                    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
                    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                        let vc = TabBarViewController()
                    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    

                }
            }
          }

        }else{

           
            guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                let vc = AuthenticationViewController()
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        }




        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
    
    func changeRootViewController(_ vc: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let window = self.window else {
            return
        }
        
        // change the root view controller to your specific view controller
        window.rootViewController = vc
        
        
        // add animation
        
            UIView.transition(with: window,
                              duration: 0.5,
                              options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
                              animations: nil,
                              completion: nil)
        

    }
```

**Comments:**

I do not know why there is a black flash when changing the root VC. Perhaps this is a bug in iOS 15 or am I missing something?

**I have tried:**

- DispatchQueue.main.async {}
- Dummy VC before API Call
- vc.view.background
  = .white

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail. You set the rootViewController in several places in the code you posted. Which one is the problem? You definitely need to ensure all UI code is run on the main queue while inside the API callback.